# Questions about badges

Tags: support, badges

How does the badge awarding process work? Does it just run queries periodically for *all* badges?
If so, how often does the system run queries to award badges?

And finally is there a way for me to see when a badge was awarded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How does the badge awarding process work? Does it just run queries periodically for all badges?

This is my understanding, yes.

> If so, how often does the system run queries to award badges?

Some badges are awarded frequently (like Nice Answer).

Rarer badges can take up to 48 hours to be awarded.

> And finally is there a way for me to see when a badge was awarded?

See other answers.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your second question: if you click the "envelope" icon by your user name, you'll be taken to a recent activity screen. It has a badges tab that will list the dates of all badges awarded within the selected timeframe.

Answer (score 1):

To see when a badge was awarded go to your profile page and then click on the badge link at the foot of the page. However, this doesn't work for all badges - e.g. the Generalist just lists who it was awarded to, not when they were awarded it.